# How to measure battery voltage?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, battery

I'm using a battery as my power supply. Is there any command or library to check the battery voltage? I want to monitor the battery discharge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add external circuitry if you want to monitor the battery voltage.

As a minimum you will need an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter) and a pair of resistors to convert the battery voltage range to a Pi safe 3V3.

You will then need to write software to read the ADC.